# Indexing with string? [Python]

Tags: python

I am learning python this semester and I came across some code I do not understand well.

```
    firstVal = examples[0][firstName]
```

where examples is list of dictionary
and firstName is a Str

Could someone help explain to me what it is doing? 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the explanation below clarified it. For some reason the dictionary thing confused me because I know you cant index into a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so basically what it is doing is it is taking the first dictionary from the list of dictionaries, and accessing the value in the key for firstName.

For ex:

examples is some thing like:

`[{'John': 'Doe', 'Jack': 'Peterson', 'Jake': 'Paul'}, {'Martin': 'Richardson', 'Luke': 'Skywalker', 'Logan': 'Paul'}]`

Doing `examples[0]`, get's you the first element of that list, which is: `{'John': 'Doe', 'Jack': 'Peterson', 'Jake': 'Paul'}`

Now, let's say firstName = 'Jack'.

Then, `examples[0][firstName]` is the same as `examples[0]['Jack']` which is `'Peterson'` because the value for the key `'Jack'` is `'Peterson'`

Please tell me if you need me to elaborate more ;)

Comment: Thank you for your input. One last question: so would this reverse the list -> examples_ = examples[1:] if not what is it doing?

Comment: No it will not reverse the list.

Comment: If `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` then `a[1:] `will return `a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` Hope that helped, and make sure to mark this answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `examples[0]` is getting the first dictionary in the list of dictionaries `examples`. Then it is accessing the key defined by the string `firstName`.

For example,

```
examples = [{'1':2, '3':4}, {'5':6, '7':8}]
firstName = '1'
firstVal = examples[0][firstName]  # will output 2
```

Comment: One last question: so would this reverse the list -> examples_ = examples[1:]  if not what is it doing?

Comment: It would not reverse a list. It would just take all the elements of a list starting from index `1` (i.e. 2nd element) and create `examples_`. This you could figure out by creating a dummy list of dictionaries as I did above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at it closely.
If `examples` is a list of dictionaries, then `examples[0]` must be the first dictionary in that list.
Then, we look for the key `firstName` in that dictionary.
We finally assign this value to `firstVal.`
So in a sentence, this line takes the first dictionary in the list, finds the value of the key `firstName`, and assigns it to `firstVal`.